# how can i delete a hash based on multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have the following list:

```
hash_list = 
{ "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153","_destroy"=>"false"},
  "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"1"},
  "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}
}
```

I need the result as:

```
{
 "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
 "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"1"},
 "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}
}
```

Basically , the `unit_id` should not repeat. But, all `_destroy=="1"`, entries can appear in the list.

Please help.

Comment: Based on what multiple values?? What is the logic behind removing "c" from the result hash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
> hash_list.to_a.uniq{|_,v|v["unit_id"] unless v["_destroy"] == "1"}.to_h

#=> {
      "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
      "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"1"},
      "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"}
    }
```

This will check for `unit_id` as uniq and also let appear `"_destory" == "1"` entries as you have mention.

Comment: There's a bug here: Only one element having `_destroy == `1 will be retained.  The others will be deleted.

Comment: @WayneConrad : let me check

Comment: @WayneConrad is well-known as a spoil-sport. He's saying that `v["unit_id"] unless v["_destroy"] == "1" #=> nil` for all values `h` for which `h["_destroy"] #=> "1"`, so `uniq` will keep only the first of those. Regretfully, I don't see a fix.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm disturbed to be well-known as a spoil-sport.  Please tell me what I've done wrong so I can correct my behavior.  You can find me in [SO chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44914/ruby-sometimes-on-rails), if you like.

Comment: @WayneConrad, anyone who spotted the problem would have been the spoil-sport, considering that Gagan had what seemed like an admirable answer. It was a good catch. I was only making jest. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Oh, humor!  Earth creatures always get me with humor.  :)

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
keepers = hash_list.select { |_k, v| v["_destroy"] == "1" }.to_h
new_hash_list = hash_list.to_a.uniq { |_k, v| v["unit_id"] }.to_h
new_hash_list.merge!(keepers)
```

When run against this data:

```
hash_list = { 
  "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"1"},
  "c"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "e"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"1"},
}
```

produces this result:

```
{
  "a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"1"},
  "e"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"1"},
}
```

Comment: I almost didn't upvote because of that misaligned `"_destroy"=>"false"`. The outer braces are also unconventional. In future, please show more respect for readers' sensibilities.

Comment: Alternatively, `keepers, no_dups = new_hash_list.partition { |_k, v| v["_destroy"] == "1" }; no_dups.uniq! { |_k,h| h["unit_id"] };
keepers.concat(no_dups).to_h`. The last line could instead be `keepers.to_h.update(no_dups.to_h)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
new_hash_list =
  { "a"=>{ "unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false" },
    "b"=>{ "unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"1"     },
    "c"=>{ "unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false" },
    "d"=>{ "unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false" },
    "e"=>{ "unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"cat", "_destroy"=>"1"     }}

require 'set'

s = Set.new
new_hash_list.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
  (h[k] = v) if v["_destroy"] == "1" || s.add?(v["unit_id"])
end
  #=> {"a"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  #    "b"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"153", "_destroy"=>"1"    },
  #    "d"=>{"unit_id"=>"42", "dep_id"=>"154", "_destroy"=>"false"},
  #    "e"=>{"unit_id"=>"43", "dep_id"=>"cat", "_destroy"=>"1"    }}
```